# jQuery Appending Element - Text doesn't fit in

Tags: jquery, css

So I have no idea why this is not working. I have the following jQuery:

```
$('#shifts').on({
    click: function(event)
    {
        selectStaff($(this));
    },
    mouseover: function()
    {
        var match = $(this);
        // There is something wrong with this user. Lets write it all down
        if( match.hasClass('warning') )
        {
            var w1 = '<div class="display_warning">This user has already been used for today.</div>';
            var w2 = '<div class="display_warning">This user is not qualified to perform one or more of the tasks assigned to this shift</div>';
            var warning = '<div id="display_warning">' + w1 + w2 + '</div>';

            match.after(warning);

        }
    },
    mouseout: function()
    {
        $('#display_warning').remove();
    }
},'.staff .match');
```

my css (below code is in LESS) for the `.display_warning` and `#display_warning` are

```
#display_warning
{
    float: left;
    width: @shiftWidth;
    background-color: @white;
    padding-top: @unit;
    padding-bottom: @unit;
    color: @textColor;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 100px;
    //border: 1px sol;
    .display_warning
    {
        float: left;
        width: @shiftWidth;
        //text-align: center;

    }
}
```

However, the text goes outside of the div and isn't constraint within the div! Why?!

Comment: i think you are defining the css of the class `.display_warning` inside the `#display_warning` .

Comment: can you include css properties inside another????!!!

Comment: and `//` is not a proper way to comment this property!!!
you have to use `/* bla bla bla : bla bla bla*/`

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, that's in LESS! So it compiles into CSS!

Comment: how about posting the compiled CSS and preferably a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) where we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Dude, the compiled version?! Take the .display_warning outside of the #display_warning, and that is the compiled version! It is not a very complicated CSS!

Comment: @user834045, just doing that won't be the compiled version, I think the properties from the `#display_warning` also apply to `.display_warning`.  Isn't that true?

Comment: No, LESS just allows you to instead of writing `#display_warning .display_error { blah : blah }` to write them inside each other. Much cleaner!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you've specified `width` and `height` for a block element.  If you remove either of those then your text will wrap within the `div`, or another option is to change them to either `min-width` if you are okay with the `div` expanding horizontally, or `min-height` if you are okay with the `div` expanding vertically.

Comment: I want the width to be fixed. I tried giving the divs min-height, but that didn't do anything!

Comment: Hmm, here is a fiddle of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ATu5K/.  Try changing the `min-height` to just `height` in the fiddle to see the difference.  You could also try adding `white-space: wrap;` option which I've commented out in the fiddle.

Comment: Strange. Could this have anything to do with the fact that the element is being dynamically added?

Comment: Shouldn't be, but you could test that easily by calling `.css(...)`, or `addClass()`